# Load menu tree of specific language drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal-7

I am working on project where I need to display menu links in other language than currently selected for example if user selects language as German then I need to display some menu items in English language.

I am currently use following to load menu in current language selected.

```
$loaded_menu = menu_tree_output(
                        i18n_menu_localize_tree(
                            menu_tree_all_data($menu_machine_name)
                        )
                    );
```

Is there anyway to load same menu in other language than currently selected.